# Reindex on sunspot rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have been trying to figure this out, but could not find the solution.
Been trying all the suggestion from stackoverflow, but none works so far.

I have setup the sunspot rails, and whenever i tried to reindex the database, its throwing me this error:

```
rake sunspot:reindex

Skipping progress bar: for progress reporting, add gem 'progress_bar' to your Gemfile

rake aborted!

RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found

Error:     NOT_FOUND



URI: http://localhost:8982/solr/default/update?wt=ruby

Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:TravelAgentAccountUser</query></delete>"



Backtrace: /Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:284:in `adapt_response'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'

(eval):2:in `post'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:82:in `update'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:146:in `delete_by_query'/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:284:in `adapt_response'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'

(eval):2:in `post'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:82:in `update'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:146:in `delete_by_query'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:57:in `remove_all'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `block in remove_all'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `each'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `remove_all'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/retry_5xx_session_proxy.rb:17:in `method_missing'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot.rb:468:in `remove_all'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:188:in `solr_remove_all_from_index'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:207:in `solr_reindex'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:58:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:57:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:69:in `with_session'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'

/Users/sabri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Tasks: TOP => sunspot:reindex

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

this is what I have on my gemfile:

```
  gem 'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'sunspot_rails'
```

and this is on the sunspot config:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

really appreciate on any help..

I have tried to install uninstall and install the gem.

Restart my laptop.

Delete the config and install again the config.

I run and stop the solr, still wouldnot work.

Thank for the help

Comment: This error is in production or development (your computer) ?. Can you attach an image of your rails app with "ls -l" command ?

Comment: this is on my development. Production is using heroku and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

`path: /solr/development`

in `sunspot.yml` configuration for the development environment.

`development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development`