# Sunspot reindexing during tests erase development indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm working on a search API which uses Sunspot for indexing and Rspec for testing.

I have a test for my search controller :

```
  context 'when doing a simple search', :type => :request do
    let!(:instance_of_my_model) { create(:instance_of_my_model) }
    it 'return the correct results' do
      MyModel.reindex

     # some test code with a GET request
    end
  end
```

For running tests, I start by lauching the solr server :

```
rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=test
```

After running my test, I stop the solr server and run it back again in development environnement. The search don't work anymore.

It works again if I reindex :

```
rake sunspot:reindex
```

(~1 hour since I have 10M+ entries)

Why is this happening ?

For information, my /config/sunspot.yml :

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, this answer : [Reindex on sunspot rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297178/reindex-on-sunspot-rails)
tipped me of.

My sunspot.yml should have been :

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development


test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```